# Is it possible to insert an icon in Microsoft Word document at a specific position, using Aspose.Word in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx, aspose, aspose.words

Is there any proper way to insert an icon at a specific position and with a specific size in a `.docx` file, by using `Aspose.Word`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to this by contacting the Aspose Support Team. And can refer in this below link: [How to insert an icon in MS Word using Aspose.Word C#](https://forum.aspose.com/t/insert-an-icon-in-docx-file-at-a-specific-position/231200)

Answer (score 0):

Aspose word document object has the `ResourceLoadingCallback` property which receives an object inherited from IResourceLoadingCallback. Write a class inherited from `IResourceLoadingCallback` and implement the `ResourceLoading` function which has the `ResourceLoadingArgs` parameter, if your html has a link to the icon image then you can extract bytes from the url and set to args setdata.

```cs
if (args.ResourceType == ResourceType.Image)
{
    if (args.Uri.Equals(ExportConstants.NoImage))
    {
        var resourceStream = GetBytesForResource(args.Uri);
        if (resourceStream != null)
        {
            args.SetData(resourceStream);
        }
    }
}
```